# MySQL query shows results, but I can't restrict by them?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hi I have a query like so

```
SELECT 
    videos.*, 
    categories.cat_name , 
    ( SELECT COUNT( * ) AS count FROM user_favorites WHERE user_id = 'tw415656866' AND video_id = videos.video_id )is_favorite 
FROM `videos` 
INNER JOIN categories 
    ON categories.cat_id = videos.cat_id 
WHERE 
    date <= '2011-11-21 09:12:18' 
GROUP BY videos.video_id 
ORDER BY (votesdown / votesup) ASC 
LIMIT 0, 5
```

This code works fine and returns a table like below

video_id     - video id
cat_name   - category name
cat_id         - category id
title             - video title
yt_id           - youtubes video id
votesup      - votes up
votesdown  - votes down
date            - date added
tweeted       - 0 / 1 ( 1=tweeted)
is_favorite   - 0 / 1 ( 1=favorited)

What i'm trying to do is add this to the WHERE clause

```
AND is_favorite = 1
```

As you can see 'is_favorite' is added to the dataset as a column but I cannot query it because MySQL says the column 'is_favorite' doesn't exist.

The exact error is...
" Unknown column 'is_favorite' in 'where clause' "

Any ideas?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_favorite` is indeed not a column but an alias for your subquery. Try using

```
HAVING is_favorite = 1
```

instead. See for example http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp for an explanation of the difference between `WHERE` and `HAVING`

So your query should look like this:

```
SELECT 
    videos.*, 
    categories.cat_name , 
    ( SELECT COUNT( * ) AS count FROM user_favorites WHERE user_id = 'tw415656866' AND video_id = videos.video_id ) AS is_favorite 
FROM `videos` 
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.cat_id = videos.cat_id 
WHERE date <= '2011-11-21 09:12:18' 
GROUP BY videos.video_id 
HAVING is_favorite = 1
ORDER BY (votesdown / votesup) ASC 
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks a lot. 2 hours of issues sorted in 20 characters. Right on!

Answer (score 1):

Due to the order in which the query is processed, the `is_favorite` alias is not available at the time the WHERE clause is evaluated. You'd need to repeat the subquery in the WHERE.

Comment: I see, do you know if theres a better more efficient way of my query?

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```
SELECT 
    videos.*, 
    categories.cat_name , 
    T.is_favorite 
FROM `videos` 
INNER JOIN categories 
    ON categories.cat_id = videos.cat_id 
Inner join 
    ( SELECT video_id, COUNT( * ) AS IsFavorite
      FROM user_favorites  
      WHERE user_id = 'tw415656866' 
      Group by video_id ) T 
        On  T.video_id = videos.video_id 
WHERE 
    date <= '2011-11-21 09:12:18' 
  And T.isFavorite =1
GROUP BY videos.video_id 
ORDER BY (votesdown / votesup) ASC 
LIMIT 0, 5
```